# C# - Reset the value of struct on class or struct

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, struct, nullable, non-nullable

I'm trying to code some script with Unity, and I have some issue to understand how struct works.

Start with a base of code:

```
 public class Engine : MonoBehaviour {

   public Hero selectedHero;
   public List<Hero> heroes;

   public struct Hero {
     public string name;
     public Hero(string n) {
       name = n;
     }
   }
 }
```

First I try to make some function to select/unselect..

```
/* ... */
public Hero getSelected(Hero h) {
  return selectedHero;
}
public void setSelected(Hero h) {
  selectedHero = h;
}
public bool hasSelected(Hero h) {
  return (selectedHero != null);
}
public void clearSelected() {
  selectedHero = null; //  This is not working ! :'(
}
/* ... */
```

And I got this error:

> Cannot convert null to `Hero` because it is a value type

I read a lot's about C# and Unity Scripting and the answer is:

> A struct can't be null in the same way that an int can't be null, and
>   a float can't be null - they're all value types

But ? What's the real solution !? I used two ugly solution to avoid this:

**Solution #1** I can put a `public bool hasSelected` and always test this one before use the `selected` attribute.

**Solution #2** Is to create a `List<Hero> selected` instead of simple `Hero` and handle if the Length is 0 or 1.

Does exist a better solution, more clean ?!

*Bonus question:* How to create a function who return a single Hero based on a test, my best (ugly) solution:

```
public Hero GetHero(string name) {
    foreach (Hero hero in heroes) {
        if (hero.name == name) {
            return hero;
        }
    }
    return null; // Not working ?! What can I return ?!
 }
```

Comment: Is there anything barring you from just making this a class? (Is there a specific reason you need this type to be a struct?) If there is some requirement, perhaps you could just make `selectedHero` a nullable with `Hero?`. Then check `.HasValue` whenever you plan to use it.

Comment: Humm I'm a JS boy.. So I don't really know. If I use a class for Hero it work the same way but I can set it to null ?

Comment: If you need an instance of a type to have a null (and not just default) value, then you probably want to use a class instead of a struct. Just swapping the keyword should be (mostly) enough.

Comment: Okay I understand, struct is kind of used to return multiple data. And class can be defined under another class (like here `Engine.Hero`) or it's better to set a new class by is own ?

Comment: Well...if you plan to reference the class in many other scripts, you might want to make it separately. (Unless it's very tightly coupled with its parent class.)

Comment: I understand now, thank you Serlite. Can you make a quick answer to be able to close this question?

Comment: Glad I could help out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need your type to be nullable, it sounds like you should make `Hero` a class (reference type) instead of a struct (value type). The changes to your code will be minimal, just swap the keyword:

```
public class Hero {
    public string name;
    public Hero(string n) {
        name = n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**About main question**:

Value types (int, struct, etc..) cannot express null in its binary representation, that's why .NET does not allow. But the .NET it has the `Nullable<T>` struct that add extra bytes for null representation.

**About select/unselect functions**

I have refactored your code to work with struct:

```
public Hero GetSelected()
{
    return selectedHero;
}

public void SetSelected(Hero h)
{
    selectedHero = h;
}

public bool HasSelected()
{
    return !(selectedHero.Equals(default(Hero)));
}

public void ClearSelected()
{
    selectedHero = default(Hero);
}
```

**About bonus question**:

That's simple, use LinQ =)

```
public Hero GetHero(string name)
{
    return heroes.Where(w => w.name.Equals(name)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

PS: The 'default value' It is other than 'Null Value'.

References:

- [Default Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)
- [Nullable Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If there is a reason you should be using Struct instead of class , then use default of to check your structs.

Some times your program may behave (or mis-behave) differently when it expects a struct and you pass a class.

So here are the changes for two of your methods:

```
       public bool hasSelected(Hero h)
        {
            return !(h.Equals(default(Hero)));
        }
        public void clearSelected()
        {
            selectedHero = default(Hero); 
        }
```

Comment: What do I win to use struct for elements like Heroes, Buildings or Items?

Comment: What do you mean by "Win to use"?